# "Error: A reference already exists for the specified id" how do I hide/fix this alert?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I'm developing a music app and if I were to go onto the page where you can play sounds, leave that page and then immediately revisit I get this error.
I've googled the problem and I can't seem to find anything similar at all.
I'm using the cordova media player and LowLatencyAudio plugin for my application.
Below is the code on the specified page and an image of the error I receive.
Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm well and truly stuck!

```
<div class="drum" id="bass" ontouchstart="play('bass');" ontouchend="touchEnd(event);">Bass</div>
    <div class="drum" id="highhat" ontouchstart="play('highhat');" ontouchend="touchEnd(event);">High Hat</div>
    <div class="drum" id="snare" ontouchstart="play('snare');" ontouchend="touchEnd(event);">Snare</div>
    <div class="drum" id="bongo" ontouchstart="play('bongo');" ontouchend="touchEnd(event);">Bongo</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

        var lla;

        function onBodyLoad() {     
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
        }

        function onDeviceReady() {
            if( window.plugins && window.plugins.LowLatencyAudio ) {

                lla = window.plugins.LowLatencyAudio;   

                lla.preloadFX('assets/bass.mp3', 'assets/bass.mp3', function(msg){}, function(msg){ alert( 'Error: ' + msg ); });
                lla.preloadFX('assets/snare.mp3', 'assets/snare.mp3', function(msg){}, function(msg){ alert( 'Error: ' + msg ); });
                lla.preloadFX('assets/highhat.mp3', 'assets/highhat.mp3', function(msg){}, function(msg){ alert( 'Error: ' + msg ); });
                lla.preloadFX('assets/bongo.mp3', 'assets/bongo.mp3', function(msg){}, function(msg){ alert( 'Error: ' + msg ); });     
            }
        }

        function play(drum) {
            document.getElementById(drum).className = 'drum touched';
            lla.play('assets/' + drum + '.mp3');
        }

        function touchEnd(event) {
            event.target.className = 'drum';
        }

    </script>
```

[image: error]

```
Error: A reference already exists for the audio id.
```

Comment: Can you add to your question, the function that is calling this alert?

Comment: I've added the javascript that's inside the same file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it is having an issue with `lla.preloadFX` being called for the same asset more than once. After reading the plugin doc, and the actual java code, This error is real a warning/notice and not an error. I have reformatted my example to show how I would ignore this message as it will not affect your application.

Here is an example:

```
function onDeviceReady() {
   if( window.plugins && window.plugins.LowLatencyAudio) {

       lla = window.plugins.LowLatencyAudio;

       lla.preloadFX('assets/bass.mp3', 'assets/bass.mp3', function(msg){}, function(msg){ if(msg != 'A reference already exists for the specified audio id.') { alert( 'Error: ' + msg ); } });
   }
}
```

Using this code, you will see an error if there is a 'real' error, otherwise it will ignore the message about the resource already being loaded. This should resolve the issue.

Comment: Although that does fix the error, now no sound is being played when I press any buttons, is your code interrupting the preload ?

Comment: upon initial load after installation I'm getting a similar alert "A reference does not exist for the specified ID." Which I get three times in a row, even though there is 4 different mp3 files.
And then I'm still getting the original error if I revisit a page.

Comment: Ok, I just read through the actual Android java code for the plugin and there is real issue trying to load a resource more than once, so what you really need to do is first check what the error is before alerting an error. If the error is that it already exists, ignore it. I will update my answer again.

Comment: OK I understand the first part but I'm not sure about the second part, how do I see the error before an error?

Comment: Sorry, got my words a little mixed up. The message you are receiving is not an error that any code is not working, it's just a message to let you know that the file was already loaded into memory. So you really don't need to catch and display that message since it will not affect your application. In the code I provided it checks to see what the message is, in the event that an actual error comes through, it will display that message, but it will ignore the message about the file already being loaded.

Comment: removing the msg functions works, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

actually deviceready event call function `lla.preloadFX` whenever you start the Application and `preloadFx()` try to load asset again those already loaded. so you can unload the assets on application exit by just handling backbutton event.

```
function onBodyLoad() {     
                document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackButton, false);
            }
       function onBackButton() {
    var assets=['bass','snare','highhat','bongo'];
                for (x in assets) {
                    lla.unload(assets[x], function (msg) {}, function (msg) {});
                }
                navigator.app.exitApp();
            }
```